# filter list where object property is equal to a string

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm trying to filter a list where the object property is equal to a string within a selected dropdownlist, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
SearchResults = FPRList.FixedPriceRepairList;
        if (ServiceTypeFilterON) {
            SearchResults = SearchResults.Where(fpr => fpr.SvcDescription = ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
```

EDIT FIXED
This does the trick!! Forgot to compare instead of assign, and also add .ToList().
ServiceTypeFilterON boolean value is checked that ddlServiceType.SelectedItem is not null btw.

```
SearchResults = FPRList.FixedPriceRepairList;
if (ServiceTypeFilterON) {
      SearchResults = SearchResults.Where(fpr => fpr.SvcDescription == ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compare values (`==`), not assign them (`=`):

```
SearchResults = SearchResults.Where(fpr => fpr.SvcDescription == ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text);
```

or

```
SearchResults = SearchResults.Where(fpr => string.Equals(fpr.SvcDescription, ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text));
```

Also make sure that `ddlServiceType.SelectedItem` is not `null` before calling this.

Comment: I'm so stupid, just  had a really bad 5 minutes!!
I also needed to use ToList() at the end.
This part of the code will only run if selectedItem is not null, that is what the ServiceTypeFilterON boolean value is doing :)

Thanks for the poke in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

You're checking for equality so it should be `==`.

```
fpr.SvcDescription == ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text
```

A single `=` is an assignment operator such as what you have in the first line

```
SearchResults = FPRList.FixedPriceRepairList;
```

You're assigning `FPRList.FixedPriceRepairList` to the `SearchResults` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the double `==`

```
fpr.SvcDescription == ddlServiceType.SelectedItem.Text
```